# Is there a way to set MotionLayout custom attribute for MaterialButton's iconTint?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout, materialbutton, constraintset

According to this [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-ii-a31acc084f59)

> CustomAttribute are specified with the attributeName, which needs to match the getter/setter methods of an object such that:
> getter: getName (e.g. getBackgroundColor)
> setter: setName (e.g. setBackgroundColor)

(so `motion:attributeName` need to be `backgroundColor`)

I've tried bellow attribute names with material button, but none of them worked.

`<CustomAttribute motion:attributeName="IconTintResource" motion:customColorValue="@color/keyTextColor" />`

`'IconTintResource',  'iconTintResource',  'IconTint',  'iconTint', 'ColorFilter'`

any suggestions?

These are the errors I'm getting

`E/TransitionLayout:  Custom Attribute "IconTint" not found on com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton`

`E/TransitionLayout: com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton must have a method setIconTint`

`E/TransitionLayout: no method setIconTinton View "f_editor_image_view_terminal"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MotionLayout's CustomAttribute use reflection to setValues on Views (roughly based on the Java beans conventions)

So if you say

```
<CustomAttribute motion:attributeName="foo" motion:customColorValue="@color/keyTextColor" />
```

It looks for a method setFoo(int value);
Unfortunately even though MaterialButton parses the xml android:iconTint="#FFF"
It does not have the method setIconTint(int color);

MotionLayout will also check for setFoo(Drawable())  and use a ColorDrawable

You can create a subclass of MaterialButton and implement the method needed
setInconTint(int color)

```
class MyButton extends MaterialButton {

    public MyButton(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyButton(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyButton(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    void setIconTint(int color) {
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(new int[1][0],new int[]{color});
        setIconTint(colorStateList);
    }
}
```

This would then work with MotionLayout. This will create many objects during animation but they will be short lived.